# PostgreSQL, how to see users in a specific group

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using PSQL.
I can create a group and drop user and add user.
My question is how to see the current member of a specific group?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Type `\du` in the psql shell

Comment: Is there any way I can see in SQL query? and I want to see one specific group under specific schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing `\du` in the psql shell will provide the Role name, List of roles, and Member of columns. I am assuming you are looking to see what each user is a member of.

Alternately, you can use this query to determine rolenames for users:

```
select rolname from pg_user join pg_auth_members on (pg_user.usesysid=pg_auth_members.member) join pg_roles on (pg_roles.oid=pg_auth_members.roleid) where pg_user.usename='USERNAME';
```

Comment: actually, I think that the original question was asking for roles in a group.  Your response is the opposite, groups a role is a member of.